# javascript ajax success function not woking?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know this has many duplicates but somehow neither of those questions (I've search almost every same title in stack overflow) work.
My problem here is that the success function does not not fire the alert message and I can't figure out why.

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" data-toggle="buttons-radio" name="optRadio" value="prof">Professor
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" data-toggle="buttons-radio" name="optRadio" value="admin">Admin
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-social" onClick="validateForm()">
    <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>Login
  </button>
</form>
```

The javascript file

```js
function validateForm() {
  var checkUser = document.getElementById("user").value;
  var checkPass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var checkOption = $("input[name=optRadio]:checked").val();
  /*
    if (checkUser && checkPass && checkOption) { //checks if user is not empty
    } else {
        alert ("Please fill up all information");
    }
  */
  if (checkOption == "prof") {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'assets/connection/login.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        user: checkUser,
        pass: checkPass,
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        alert("a")
      },
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response)
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and the php file only contains this

```
<?php echo "js test" ?>
```

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out in comments and by @[Rax Weber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045104/rax-weber)'s answer, there was a typographical mistake in `sucess` (*should be `success`*), but this is not the root cause of problem and still `alert` does not fires after correcting it.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, have you opened your Developer Console in your browser and checked for Javascript errors?  That might help with figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: Hmm.. I'am using Chrome to debug based on the console returns and unfortunately it does not return anything.

Comment: By “does not work” do you mean that the `alert` doesn’t fire at all or it doesn’t display the result you wanted? Look at the “Network” tab in the dev tools. Does the AJAX request actually get sent? Does it return an HTTP error like 404 or 403?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, are you saying you get an empty alert or no alert at all?  (also, have you confirmed that your AJAX call actually succeeds?

Comment: @Cedirck I have rollback your edit. If its a typo mistake thats causing issue, you should opt to delete question as it will not add much to portal

Comment: @Rajesh Based on the comments in this thread, there seems to be another issue on top of the typo.  I disagree with your rollback.

Comment: @Rajesh Your rollback was incorrect. There indeed was a typo, but the code still does not work. The issue still exists. There still needs to be a question open about the OP’s actual issue. The issue is not the typo, so the version with `success` needs to be the current one.

Comment: @Xufox I'm currently working at localhost so I don't know if that affects what network tab returns but as I've observe it does not return any error

Comment: @Xufox in that case, we can add a caveat. If we fix typo in question, Rax's answer will become pointless and will attract downvotes for no reason.

Comment: Also with does not work I meant the alert does not fire.

Comment: I see this becoming a long conversation, so let's continue this here for now:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136060/javascript-ajax-sucess-not-working

Comment: @Rajesh Such is fate. If an answer turns out to be not useful, then it might need to be downvoted or deleted. On the other hand, _answering_ typo questions always comes with this risk…

Comment: @KyleMartin unfortunately the chatroom requires 20 rep and currently im on 6.

Comment: @Xufox agreed. Its bad to answer a typo, but its also bad to update your question based on someone answer. This will make their answer void and irrelevant. We should edit and credit them in question but not change original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that, you have set `dataType: 'json'`, and not getting response in JSON.
Possible solutions:

1. Send the response in **JSON**.
   In you post file, send JSON encoded output: `<?php echo json_encode("js test"); ?>`
2. Let the dataType be set to default. Remove the line `dataType: 'json'` from your JS.

Comment: Got it! It works fine now. Actually my original code does not have the datatype. I just assumed it was because through searching i found out that json returns string and im actually echoing string. So all in all the problem was the semantic error in the success section. Thanks for pointing out the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It should  be **success**, not sucess.

```
sucess: function (response) {
  ^
    alert (response)
}
```

**Edit:** The question has been updated/edited. Previously, it had a semantics mistake as I have mentioned above.

Comment: It's always the little details that'll get you

Comment: For the love of what!! all it was is a TYPO! :/ Thanks alot! but I am wondering if it is a typo then how come it is still colored? (sublime)

Comment: Some editors (especially simple ones) often highlight based on just the structure, not the actual syntax.  So it sees what that word is supposed to be based on the structure of your code and it highlights it.  (That probably made no sense, but I tried)   :)

Comment: @KyleMartin got your point there. Though still it does not work for some reason after the edit.

Comment: Just a pointer, this should have been a comment and you should have closed it as its a typographical mistake.

Comment: @Rajesh actually I thought typographical was all the error. But somehow after correcting the syntax the success function still does not work.

Comment: @Cedirck Just a minor detail: `sucess` vs. `success` isn’t a syntax issue, it’s a semantic issue.

Comment: @Rax Weber, Please read comments under question as they make your answer irrelevant and might attract downvotes

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer.